Open problems in differential algebra and affine algebraic geometry
I am currently doing a PhD in differential algebra and affine algebraic geometry at the University of Buenos Aires. I've been struggling to find a list of interesting and big open problems in these areas. I would be interested in a list of problems or also a list of subtopics that are currently on trend together with a list of reasons about their importance/influence in the area.

I believe one such direction would be that of the Jacobian Conjecture (and polynomial automorphisms and derivations). It's probably the most (in)famous of that kind, but there are a lot of other open problems surrounding it or related to it where very little is known. You may want to check out van den Essen's book on polynomial automorphisms for further info and ideas. There are also more recent surveys.
